# AngularJS bind to dynamic html

Tags: angularjs

given this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1356/

I have an array of objects retrieved from my service.  I then build an html string with links created around those items that exist in the array.  I want the click handler to be bound directly to item in the array.  The behavior I'm after is the way an object can be passed directly into a ngClick when used within a ngRepeat.

```
//these were retrieved from a service first
$scope.termsToBindTo = [
    {name: 'test 1', active: false },
    {name: 'test 2', active: false },
    {name: 'test 3', active: false }];

$scope.rawString = 'test 1, test 2, and test 3';    

//then this html string was built after termsToBindTo is populated
$scope.myHTML = '<a href="#" ng-click="itemClicked(item)">test 1</a>, <a href="#" ng-click="itemClicked(item)">test 2</a>, and <a href="#" ng-click="itemClicked(item)">test 3</a>';
```

UPDATE: i added the rawString to the controller.  I considered the suggestion below to just use ngRepeat over termsToBindTo but my view must present the links just as rawString looks.  In other words I cannot just provide a list of termsToBindTo.  The view has to provide the links with any formatting or punctuation that exist in rawString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zABM/1/)

You can use whatever punctuation and display format you need with ngRepeat and couple of nested `spans`:

```
<span data-ng-repeat="term in termsToBindTo">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="itemClicked(term)">{{term.name}}</a><span ng-show="$index == termsToBindTo.length - 2">, and </span><span ng-show="$index < termsToBindTo.length - 2">, </span>
</span>
```

Comment: thanks!  i didn't do exactly what you described but it got me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but you should use ng-repeat :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="term in termsToBindTo">
 <a href="#" data-ng-click="itemClicked(term)" data-ng-bind="term.name"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I did consider this but it doesnt work with my requirements.  please see updated questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @package I ended up ripping the string into pieces:

```
test 1, test 2, test 3, and test 4
[0] --> [test 1]
[1] --> [, ]
[2] --> [test 2]
[3] --> [, ]
[4] --> [test 3]
[5] --> [, and ]
[6] --> [test 4]
```

then ngRepeat over them with a ngSwitch on a property that exists on each object in the above array to either show an href or static text.